# API code to add/modify text into the lync conversation window

Tags: lync

I'd like to read the conversation window of MS Lync and either reformat some text in it, or if that is not possible, to add a new formatted text at the bottom of it (I want to make it clickable).

Is there a way to modify or add new text to the Lync conversation window via the API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Lync SDK to read instant message. Event InstantMessageReceived can be used.

```
public event EventHandler<MessageSentEventArgs> InstantMessageReceived
```

[MSDN Link - InstantMessageReceived](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.lync.model.conversation.instantmessagemodality.instantmessagereceived_di_3_uc_ocs14mreflyncclnt.aspx)

AFAIK, there is no way to modify an incoming message. However, there is a way to send message to conversation using BeginSendMessage method. The message can be send in plain or formatted text.

[MSDN Link - SendMessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.lync.model.conversation.instantmessagemodality.beginsendmessage_di_3_uc_ocs14mreflyncclnt.aspx)